# Reverse Get item by foreign key django template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build CMS like menu models.

So in **MODELS.PY**:

```
class MenuItem(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "menu_item"
        verbose_name = "Menu Item"
        verbose_name_plural = "Menu Items"

    menu_item_title = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Menu Item Custom URL title",
        max_length=200,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    menu_item_type = models.ForeignKey(
        MenuType,
        related_name="menu_item_type_key",
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )

class MenuItemCustomUrl(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "menu_item_custom_url"
        verbose_name = "Menu Item Custom URL"
        verbose_name_plural = "Menu Items Custom URL"

    menu_item_custom_url = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="URL address that points menu item",
        max_length=200,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    menu_item_custom_url_menu_item = models.ForeignKey(
        MenuItem,
        unique=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="menu_item_custom_url_menu_item_key",
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
```

in **VIEWS.PY**:

```
def homepage(request):
    args['menu_items'] = MenuItem.objects.filter(menu_item_menu=args['main_menu'])
    return render(request, template_page, args)
```

and **TEMPLATE**:

```
{% for menu_item in menu_items %}
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            {{ menu_item }}
        </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

So, as you see the every **menu_item** has attached **menu_item_custom_url**, and what I need is to use  menu_item_custom_url value in menu_item loop

**NOTE**: Beside custopm_url type there are also other types with their own parameter...

*virtualenv, django=1.11, python=3.4, ubuntu=14.04*

Comment: The easiest way is probably to create accessors in your `MenuItem` class.

Comment: Can you explain please?

Comment: `my_menu_item.menuitemcustomurl_set.filter(...)` will get you the set of `MenuItemCustomUrl` records that have fkeys to `my_menu_item`. If you create a method in `MenuItem` that does the above, finds the record you're interested in, and returns it... then you can use this method from your template.

Comment: {{ menu_item.menu_item_custom_url_menu_item_key }} gives "mega_admin.MenuItemCustomUrl.None"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extend your model with a method to find the correct sub-object:

```
class MenuItem(models.Model):
    def custom_url(self):
        return self.menuitemcustomurl_set.first()  # assume the first one is correct
    ...
```

then you can use this method in you template directly

```
{{ menu_item.custom_url }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I can use that directly in template